# how to display div in front of <header> element

Tags: css, z-index, drupal-theming

How can I display a div that is outside the `<header>` element in front of the header i.e. with a higher `z-index`. I've tried to use the `z-index` property but it doesn't seem to work. My particular example can be seen here: http://www.spabc.com/drupal/ I want to display the logo on the right side in front of the header bar.

Comment: What about placing it inside the `header` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `#logo`.

```
#logo {position: relative;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
position: relative;
```

to `#logo` will work. As for `z-index`, it does not work on default positioned elements. The standard `position` property is `static`.

> z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Read more about z-index [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

### Default element stacking

I read this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index), figured I'd go through it first before posting it here.

When no z-index is present in the element's properties, elements are stacked in the following order, 3 being the one the furthest in the back:

1. Background and borders of the root element
2. Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in HTML)
3. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance (in HTML)

There are still rules that go with this order.

> - If the `position` value of multiple overlapping objects is the same, the order is given by their position in the HTML document.
> - If a `position` value is not set, it defaults to the `static` value. `static` elements will always fall behind elements that have a
>     `position` value.

```css
div {
  font: 12px Arial;
}
span.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#normdiv {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px dashed #999966;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#reldiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed #669966;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#reldiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed #669966;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#absdiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
#absdiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="absdiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #1</span>
  <br />position: absolute;
</div>

<div id="reldiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #2</span>
  <br />position: relative;
</div>

<div id="reldiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #3</span>
  <br />position: relative;
</div>

<div id="absdiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #4</span>
  <br />position: absolute;
</div>

<div id="normdiv">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #5</span>
  <br />no positioning
</div>
```

### Stacking without z-index on floating objects

For floating blocks the stacking order is a bit different. Floating blocks are placed between non-positioned blocks and positioned blocks:

1. Background and borders of the root element
2. Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in
   HTML)
3. Floating blocks
4. Inline descendants in the normal flow
5. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance (in HTML)

```css
div {
  font: 12px Arial;
}
span.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#absdiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 140px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
#normdiv {
  /* opacity: 0.7; */
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #999966;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
#flodiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #009900;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  text-align: center;
}
#flodiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #009900;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  text-align: center;
}
#absdiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 130px;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="absdiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #1</span>
  <br />position: absolute;
</div>

<div id="flodiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #2</span>
  <br />float: left;
</div>

<div id="flodiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #3</span>
  <br />float: right;
</div>

<br />

<div id="normdiv">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #4</span>
  <br />no positioning
</div>

<div id="absdiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #5</span>
  <br />position: absolute;
</div>
```

Comment: Great theoretical part about `z-index` :-) And are you able to clarify how it works when there is no `z-index` in CSS code?

Comment: I read through the MDN just after I read your comment. I added it in my answer, even though it wasn't picked as the answer by the OP. Simply for convenience, I guess. Thanks anyhow @panther! I actually did learn something myself by reading that.